# MySQL create view joining two whole tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

How can I create a view that merges different all columns from two different tables.

```
CREATE VIEW listView 
AS 
SELECT * FROM tab1 h LEFT JOIN tab2 b 
ON h.tID=b.tID 
WHERE value = 0
```

this give me the error:

> Duplicate column name 'tID'

Is there a way to join the two tables without listing all the values to select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two tables contains columns `tID`. In order to compile the `VIEW`, you need to create an alias on that column or just specify one `tid` and table where it will come from.

One solution:

```
SELECT  h.TID, -- and not specifying b.TID
FROM    tab1 h LEFT JOIN tab2 b ON h.tID=b.tID
```

Another solution: supply an alias,

```
SELECT  h.TID as H_TID,
        b.TID as B_TID
FROM    tab1 h LEFT JOIN tab2 b ON h.tID=b.tID
```

Comment: I used h.* to select all column from one table and then alias for colomns in the second table

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW listView 
AS 
SELECT
  a.tID as a_tID,
  b.tID as b_tID,
  a.anothercolumn as a_anothercolumn,
  b.anothercolumn as b_anothercolumn
FROM tab1 a
JOIN tab2 b ON a.tID=b.tID 
WHERE a.value = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your column names instead of using * and then alias your columns like this:

```
SELECT h.tId, b.tId as BTId
```

You can't have the same name twice -- hence your error above.