# Merge and sort two mysql tables with different columns

Tags: php, mysql

Table 1: user posts

```
+----+----------+-------------+--------+------+------+---------------------+
| id | parentID | commenterID | userID | post | tags |        date         |
+----+----------+-------------+--------+------+------+---------------------+
|  1 | NULL     |           1 |      2 | hi   | NULL | 2013-08-01 16:24:49 |
+----+----------+-------------+--------+------+------+---------------------+
```

Table 2: blog posts

```
+----+------+------+----------+-------+------+-------+----------+---------------------+
| id | type | tags | username | title | body | views | comments |        date         |
+----+------+------+----------+-------+------+-------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | post | tag1 | user1    | lol   | test |     0 |        0 | 2013-08-29 21:58:52 |
+----+------+------+----------+-------+------+-------+----------+---------------------+
```

I am trying to merge these two tables and sort them by date. None of these tables have anything in common so I am afraid I cannot use JOIN.

Table 1 represents "user posts" and table 2 represents "blog posts". I am building a "stream" of information such as it displays in the user's feed any updates/new posts coming in.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did you consider defining a view in the database layer? You want to do SELECT a AS foo, b AS bar... FROM table1 UNION aa AS foo, bb as bar... FROM table2

Comment: Try out the answers set in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187751/mysql-create-view-joining-two-whole-tables

Comment: I would have suggested using UNION

Comment: Thanks, David Brossard. mysql isn't my strong suit. Cheers